# Dynamic Programming: The number of arrangements of the columns

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

We have $n$ objects. (They are similar, like $n$ nuts)

The objective is to arrange these objects in some columns beside each other such that the height of each column is more than the height of its previous column.

> Using the Dynamic Programming approach, Provide an algorithm of
>   $O(n^3)$ for finding the number of possible arrangements of these
>   objects.

I was thinking of dividing the problem into some subproblems and storing the result of them in an array. But, i don't know how! So, i'm stuck... I'm not sure if i'm thinking the right way...

Any idea? Can u provide an algorithm?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I've seen a very similar problem on some Online Judge, but I don't remember the exact solution. However, I do remember that this problem is related to the problem of decomposition number into terms. Consider one object as 1 (number). So you just need to compute number of ways how you can decompose $n$ into non-negative terms, such every term is bigger than previous term. So, you may want to read some articles on how to decompose number using dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution, but a suggestion of one possible way to think about the problem in terms of triangular numbers.

The $m$-th triangular number is defined as

$$ T_m=1+2+3+\cdots+m=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$

A triangular number of objects has a **canonical** stacking $\mathcal{S}_m$ where each column contains exactly one more object than the column to its right.

Suppose $k$ is a positive integer and

$$ T_m<k<T_{m+1}$$

Then call the canonical stacking of $\mathcal{S}_k$ of $k$ the canonical stacking of $m$ with one of the $m-k$ excess objects placed on the leftmost column of $\mathcal{S}_m$, one on the next column to the right, etc until all $m-k$ excess objects are exhausted.

In this manner there is only one canonical stacking $\mathcal{S}_k$ for each positive integer $k$.

Now all other stackings satifying the condition may be viewed as a canonical stacking for some $k$ with one or more columns removed to produce a **substacking** $\mathcal{S}_k^\prime$ of $\mathcal{S}_k$.

So for each canonical stacking for $k$ objects, how many substackings are there and how many objects are in each substacking?

Note that for each $k$ one should not count substackings already considered for smaller values of $k$. One should only consider substackings which include the leftmost column of the stacking.

Offered solely as one possible way of thinking about the exercise.

**Addendum:** I just noticed (what should have been immediately obvious) that if $T_m<k<T_{m+1}$ then $\mathcal{S}_k$ is a substacking of $\mathcal{S}_{m+1}$ with a single column removed.

**Update**

There is a one-to-one correspondence between each positive binary integer and the possible stack arrangements.

The first stack pictured is a **full stack** which contains all $n$ columns. Included columns are associated with a $1$ bit and absent columns with a $0$ bit. Since the full $n-stack$ has all $n$ columns present it is represented by a binary string of $n$ $1$'s, so the full $n-stack$ is associated uniquely with the binary number $2^n-1$.

For further explanation the second diagram shows the sub-stack $\mathcal{S}_{45}$ of the $6-stack$.

The full $6$-stack is $\mathcal{S}_{63}$.

The smallest $m$-stack containing at least $n$ blocks is is $m=\left\lceil\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{8n}}{2}\right\rceil$ and the largest is $m=n$. For the $n$-stack, there is only one sub-stack containing exactly $n$ blocks, namely $\mathcal{S}_{2^{n-1}}$.

As for designing a counting algorithm of order $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ using the Dynamic Programming approach, I have no idea. I learned to program in Fortran in 1962 and other than Fortran 95, bc and Javascript I have not used any of the more modern languages or techniques.

But I hope this method of associating each stack with a unique binary number can prove useful.

[image: the n-stack][image]

Comment: This could be somewhat related:   https://books.google.com/books?id=W1Nso5E6G3YC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=how+many+ways+to+write+n+as+a+sum+of+unequal+numbers&source=bl&ots=YlTqfwYJGY&sig=gkrchZLbNto42zCLLmKuP5RrAlQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSpqiAipbUAhWBzIMKHXWUDUwQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=how%20many%20ways%20to%20write%20n%20as%20a%20sum%20of%20unequal%20numbers&f=false